# CMD Script for-loop run multiple variable executable files

Tags: windows, variables, for-loop, cmd, executable

I'm working on a - I thought - simple script, which can install multiple programs.

So let's see, this is my directory with the mandatory files.

- C:\variables.ini
- C:\programs.txt
- C:\update.cmd
- C:\scan.cmd
- C:\storage\ *.exe

Example for *.exe is "scribus-1.4.4-windows-x64.exe"

variables.ini contains

```
prog=C:\programs.txt
```

programs.txt contains

```
scribus-1.4.4-windows-x64.exe
```

scan.cmd contains

```
dir C:\storage /b /a-d > programs.txt
```

Now the problem: update.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL 
REM Read variables
for /f %%i in (C:\variables.ini) do set %%i
cd C:\storage\
for /f %%i in %prog% do %%i /Q /S
ping localhost -n 5 > nul
del %%i
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
exit
```

How works the update.cmd?

I've a main .cmd from there I call multiple .cmd files which do several things. As you see, I run in the first place the scan.cmd. It scans the c:\storage\ dir and write the content into c:\programs.txt. In the variables.ini is the programs.txt file as %prog% variable embedded. Now I run update.cmd and it takes the first variable program from the programs.txt, in this case scribus, and start the install with /silent and /quiet flag (some programms use /s and others /q, but not both, maybe a possible bug, but I had no better idea). After the install it waits for 5 seconds and remove the .exe file. If there are other executables, then the script start again til the storage dir is empty.

I hope you understand me... I tried some other ways, but I failed.
So I tried it without the variables file and executed the scan command inside the update.cmd

```
@ECHO & SETLOCAL 
cd C:\storage\
for /F %%i in ('dir C:\storage /b /a-d') do set %%i
%%i /Q /S
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
pause
```

There I get some errors, that scribus is no environment variable. I don't know why it should be anyone? I tried google and read many tutorials and threads about for-loops, but not one person executed a setup file from a variable.

Does anyone know a way how I can fix this?
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Noting that your paths are horrible: don't install things into the root of the system drive.

As is `cmd.exe`: PowerShell is the future and vastly more powerful. And using `ping` for a delay (it sends the next ping as soon as the previous received: so not a good timing mechanism).

But I think all you need to do it launch executables is

```
start /wait command
```

which will not return until command has finished.

You also seem to be trying to run multiple commands in a `for` loop in cmd, this is possible:

```
for /F %%i in ('dir C:\storage /b /a-d') do set %%i && %%i /Q /S
```

using `&&` to separate the commands (it is not clear why you have `set %%i`: it will just list variables with the name, you're not setting a value).

Comment: Please ignore my stupid try I posted at the end of my post. The first long cmd script is relevant. I've already a similar script for wake on lan (there it works!), but there I call wol.exe (for /f %%i in (%mac_addresses%) do %wol% %%i), I thought I can use this for my installing idea, too. But it doesn't work. EDIT: The path c:\ is for testing, later on it's stored in C:\scripts\, I thought it's meaningless if I try to run it for tests directly in C:\

Comment: @user3048888 Cmd is *very* limited. While much can be achieved, once you are thinking in data files you would be better spending your time on something with the right kind of capabilities (ie. PowerShell). Eg. PSH can perform a WMI query for a list of MAC addresses easily, or wait on a process to exit.

Comment: I know the limitations, but I've no experience in psh. It's for a normal Windows 7 PC. Just to mention, I've already many scripts finished and all of them work. This one is the last one, it's frustrating if I must start over again for this one. :(

Comment: @user3048888 One of the problems with cmd is the difficulty in debugging: a small change can break everything. All you can do is strip things down and build them up again hoping to avoid a new fault. Lots of `echo` can help, but in the end it is a very weak tool. If this kind of scripting is a common need, then the investment in a modern, actively maintained tool designed for serious scripting will pay for itself many times (PSH v2 is included in Win7, albeit new versions are available to install.)

Comment: PSH v2 is for sure a good utility, but PSH is again such a M$ thing, that invents the wheel again. I simply want fixing my for-loop and don't know how. As you can read, it works a little bit, but the install for scribus doesn't start, it's not in the variable %%i. In %%i ist just programs.txt not the content. So how I get the content inside the variable (it must not be %%i) so I can install and after that, delete the setup file?

Comment: Okay I found my error... for /f %%i in %prog% do %%i /Q /S --- I just forgot the brackets by %prog%.